# Pandas groupby given time interval

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that is of 5 minute intervals. I would like to compute returns given a time internal specified by the user. For example I like to know the return everyday from 2:55PM to 3:00PM. How do I perform group by operations on that?

my data looks like this

```
                               Open      High       Low     Close  Volume           VB           VS     MCVol         MCVal   OpenInt    Ret  TotalRet
date                                                                                                                                                  
2019-07-12 14:40:00+08:00  0.411629  0.412154  0.411366  0.411891  2412.0  408971474.0  414685176.0  315290.0  3.007625e+10  556102.0   25.0   41975.0
2019-07-12 14:45:00+08:00  0.411891  0.413205  0.411629  0.412942  6536.0  408975390.0  414687662.0  318884.0  3.041836e+10  556200.0  100.0   42075.0
2019-07-12 14:50:00+08:00  0.412942  0.413205  0.411891  0.412680  3288.0  408976658.0  414689656.0  320962.0  3.061613e+10  555638.0  -25.0   42050.0
2019-07-12 14:55:00+08:00  0.412680  0.414254  0.412417  0.413992  5926.0  408980236.0  414691758.0  324190.0  3.092359e+10  555482.0  125.0   42175.0
2019-07-12 15:00:00+08:00  0.413729  0.413992  0.412417  0.412942  8190.0  408983450.0  414696208.0  329278.0  3.140824e+10  553480.0 -100.0   42075.0
```

Most of the questions asked are solved via resample which I am not sure fits my situation. Mine is more a mix of using `between_time()` and groupby.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution (assuming the **Close** column for return computation).
Edit: Not sure what you meant by groupby though since the price series is continuously recorded every five minutes. Groupby starting time 14.55 across different stocks?

```
import pandas as pd

ind = pd.date_range('2019-07-12 14:40', periods=5, freq='5min')
stock = {'Close':[0.411891,0.412942,0.412680,0.413992,0.412942]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=stock,index=ind)

print(df)

output = df.between_time('14:55','15:00')['Close'].pct_change().iloc[1]

print('Return-----')
print(output)
```

Output

```
                        Close
2019-07-12 14:40:00  0.411891
2019-07-12 14:45:00  0.412942
2019-07-12 14:50:00  0.412680
2019-07-12 14:55:00  0.413992
2019-07-12 15:00:00  0.412942
Return-----
-0.0025362808943169
```

Edit2: I know what you meant now. Try this.

```
import pandas as pd

ind = pd.date_range('2019-07-12 14:40', periods=5, freq='5min')
ind = ind.append(pd.date_range('2019-07-13 14:40', periods=5, freq='5min'))

stock = {'Close':[0.411891,0.412942,0.412680,0.413992,0.412942,0.423567,0.456321,0.465789,0.431900,0.431672]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=stock,index=ind)
df.rename_axis('date',inplace=True)
df['date_'] = df.index.date
print(df)

print(df.between_time('14:55','15:00')['Close'])

output = df.between_time('14:55','15:00').groupby('date_').pct_change().iloc[1::2]

print('Return-----')
print(output)
```

Output

```
Return-----
                        Close
date
2019-07-12 15:00:00 -0.002536
2019-07-13 15:00:00 -0.000528
```

Edit3: This new code is robust towards overlapping of days and more-than-5-minute return. I used a 15-minute return as an example (23:55-00:05).

```
import pandas as pd

ind = pd.date_range('2019-07-12 23:50', periods=5, freq='5min')
ind = ind.append(pd.date_range('2019-07-13 23:50', periods=5, freq='5min'))

stock = {'Close':[0.411891,0.412942,0.412680,0.413992,0.412942,0.423567,0.456321,0.465789,0.431900,0.431672]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=stock,index=ind)
df.rename_axis('date',inplace=True)
print(df)

# I am setting this manually, you may improve it by writing a function that calculates
# the number of five-minute interval
num =2

ind = df.between_time('23:55','00:05').iloc[::num+1]['Close'].index

old_price = df.between_time('23:55','00:05')['Close'].iloc[::num+1].reset_index(drop=True)
new_price = df.between_time('23:55','00:05')['Close'].iloc[num::num+1].reset_index(drop=True)
#print(old_price)
#print(new_price)

output = pd.DataFrame(new_price/old_price-1)
output.set_index(ind,inplace=True)

print('Return-----')
print(output)
```

Output

```
                        Close
date
2019-07-12 23:50:00  0.411891
2019-07-12 23:55:00  0.412942
2019-07-13 00:00:00  0.412680
2019-07-13 00:05:00  0.413992
2019-07-13 00:10:00  0.412942
2019-07-13 23:50:00  0.423567
2019-07-13 23:55:00  0.456321
2019-07-14 00:00:00  0.465789
2019-07-14 00:05:00  0.431900
2019-07-14 00:10:00  0.431672
Return-----
                        Close
date
2019-07-12 23:55:00  0.002543
2019-07-13 23:55:00 -0.053517
```

Comment: this doesn't work because I only care about 2:55PM to 3:00PM. The between time will compute returns for 3Pm to next days 2:55 PM too....

Comment: @user1234440 Just realized I had forgotten to comment out the first two print statements in my new code. You may leave them there to help you understand.

Comment: this is almost there, but the data contains across day data. So imagine I want to find return from 11PM  to 1AM. This is across 2 days....would groupby work?

Comment: @user1234440 It wouldn't in that case it the days overlap. In that case, I suggest you shift the time index artificially by negative 120 minutes, i.e. 9PM to 11PM. Using this trick, perform the groupby calculation, and then shift the time index back for display. An important thing to note is that my code was written for return computation for 5 minutes only. If you want a more than 5-minute return (e.g. 2-hour return), you have to change the 2 of the iloc[1::2] part appropriately. I hope that helps.

Comment: @user1234440 See edit 3. The time shifting trick wasn't needed. I had made it worked without just by manipulating iloc[::] part appropriately. I hope it helps.